# Can calls to printf() block?

Tags: ssh, terminal, stdout

How does printf() (or writes to stdout in general) work regarding flow control and buffering? Is printf() guaranteed to return in reasonable amount of time, or will it block until it was actually able to write something to stdout?

I'm thinking about a slow SSH connection or something like that. Can that actually slow down some program at a printf()? Will that occur immediately, or only after some buffer has been filled up (some internal buffer of stdout, or possibly even the TCP send buffer)? Does using SSH make some other difference, besides possibly increasing latency and decreasing output speed?

If so, how is that circumvented? Are threads a common solution to that problem, or is there some easier way to set a flag or do a call to switch stdout to "non-blocking mode"? Or do I have some basic facts about the workings of Unix I/O completely wrong and the question doesn't make any sense? :)

I'm asking mainly out of interest, but the issue has recently come up on two occasions during experimenting with C and the shell, and I wonder where and how it should be addressed in general:

- When developing an application that potentially does lots of output to the terminal for debugging or information purposes, can slow terminals potentially cause performance issues? Should I (as a programmer) avoid constructs like (for each x in y: print y) for large lists?
- Or is that a problem that should best be handled by the application user instead of the developer, by redirecting the output to a file etc.? If so, are there any useful shell idioms to decouple program output from the actual execution, like `mytool | cat` (I'm not sure if that particular example would actually change anything, but cat could be replaced by something more sophisticated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, calls to `printf()` could block. One example is `stdout` connected to a pipe with a slow reader at the other end.

Whether this is an issue or how best to mitigate it really depends on the nature of the application, and *why* it's an issue in the first place.

Comment: It's mainly out of interest, motivated by some experimenting with C and input/output redirection. I added that to my question.